# Windows API screenshot only updated once

Tags: windows, winapi, rust, gdi

I am trying to get a screenshot of another application's window with this rust code. It works the first time it is run, however following screenshots are the exact same bitmap as the first screenshot. Even rerunning my program results in the same bitmap. It is only updated once I close and restart the app I am trying to screenshot.

draw_cleanup simply selects the old object, deleted the mem_dc and releases the dc.

```rust
pub unsafe fn screen_capture(hwnd: HWND) -> Option<HBITMAP> {
    let dimensions = window_dimensions(hwnd)?;
    
    let hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
    let mem_hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    let bitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, dimensions.0 as i32, dimensions.1 as i32);
    let old = SelectObject(mem_hdc, bitmap as *mut c_void);

    let result = PrintWindow(hwnd, mem_hdc, PW_CLIENTONLY);

    if result == 0 {
        draw_cleanup(hwnd, hdc, mem_hdc, old).ok()?;
        DeleteObject(bitmap as *mut c_void);
        return None
    }

    draw_cleanup(hwnd, hdc, mem_hdc, old).ok()?;
    Some(bitmap)
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you could try to use [the BitBlt function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-bitblt) to captures images. For more details, you could refer to the Doc:[Capturing an Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/capturing-an-image)

Comment: Thanks but I had originally used that instead of PrintWindow, same problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, I had to use the PW_RENDERFULLCONTENT flag on the PrintWindow. Weird that this has no documentation.

Comment: `PrintWindow` is **not** the way to take a screenshot of a window. Handling the respective messages is at the discretion of the implementor of the window class. A valid implementation is free to ignore those messages altogether. The supported API is [`Windows.Graphics.Capture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.capture). See [screenshot-rs](https://github.com/robmikh/screenshot-rs) for sample code.